# send get parameters using action attribute of form and even send the form elements

Tags: html

I want to sent parameters using action and even the value of input name=edit parameters but only

```
ajaxify/modify.php?edit=something 
is sent instead of 
ajaxify/modify.php?f=update&id=5&edit=something
```

Is there any solution for this or I am doing some blunder. Please help me.

```
<form id="update" action="ajaxify/modify.php?f=update&id=5">
    <input type="text" name="edit" value="something"/>
    <input type="submit" value="update"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `hidden` input. This will work for get/post methods. Example:

```
<form id="update" action="ajaxify/modify.php">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="f" value="update"/>
    <input type="text" name="edit" value="something"/>
    <input type="submit" value="update"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `method` attribute of the `form` element to `get` to make it do a `get` instead of a `post`.

```
<form id="update" action="ajaxify/modify.php?f=update&id=5" method="get">
```

Comment: sorry You got my question wrong and get it by default if we dont mention is specifically..anyways the above answer is what i was looking for..anyways thanks for reply.